# Type erasure: Retrieving value - type check at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-erasure, crtp

I have a limited set of very different types, from which I want to store instances in a single collection, specifically a map. To this end, I use the type erasure idiom, ie. I have a non-templated base class from which the templated, type specific class inherits:

```
struct concept
{
   virtual std::unique_ptr<concept> copy() = 0; // example member function
};

template <typename T>
struct model : concept
{
   T value;
   std::unique_ptr<concept> copy() override { ... }
}
```

I then store unique_ptrs to concept in my map. To retrieve the value, I have a templated function which does a dynamic cast to the specified type.

```
template <typename T>
void get(concept& c, T& out) {
   auto model = dynamic_cast<model<T>>(&c);
   if (model == nullptr) throw "error, wrong type";
   out = model->value;
}
```

What I don't like about this solution is, that specifying a wrong T is only detected at runtime. I'd really really like this to be done at compile time.

My options are as I see the following, but I don't think they can help here:

- Using ad hoc polymorphism by specifying free functions with each type as an overload, or a template function, but I do not know where to store the result.

  - Using CRTP won't work, because then the base class would need to be templated.
  - Conceptually I would need a virtual function which takes an instance of a class where the result will  be stored. However since my types are fundamentally different, this class would need to be templated, which does not work with virtual.

Anyways, I'm not even sure if this is logically possible, but I would be very glad if there was a way to do this.

Comment: The whole point of type erasure is to move type resolution to the runtime. A compile-time check doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Also: you should avoid throwing raw strings, use `std::exception` instead.

Comment: You probably want `variant` instead of your base class. and in both case, you might use visitor.

Comment: You mention a map, out of curiosity, what are you keying off of? if by chance it's `std::type_index`, you might get away with not having a compile-time check and instead rely on a class invariant that `map[type]` is guaranteed to be a `model<type>`.

Comment: The key is a "tag" struct of two integers, and unfortunately one tag may have different model types.

Comment: @MariusHerzog a shame. I'll still leave my answer, as it might come in handy for someone else stumbling on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a limited set of types, your best option is `variant`. You can operate on a variant most easily by specifying what action you would take for every single variant, and then it can operate on a variant correctly. Something along these lines:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::variant<Foo, Bar>> m;

m["a_foo"] = Foo{};
m["a_bar"] = Bar{};

for (auto& e : m) {
    std::visit(overloaded([] (Foo&) { std::cerr << "a foo\n"; }
                          [] (Bar&) { std::cerr << "a bar\n"; },
               e.second);
}
```

`std::variant` is c++17 but is often available in the experimental namespace beforehand, you can also use the version from boost. See here for the definition of overloaded: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit (just a small utility  the standard library unfortunately doesn't provide).

Of course, if you are expecting that a certain key maps to a particular type, and want to throw an error if it doesn't, well, there is no way to handle that at compile time still. But this does let you write visitors that do the thing you want for each type in the variant, similar to a virtual in a sense but without needing to actually have a common interface or base class.

Comment: This is probably what  I want. I don't expect a certain key to map to a particular type, just that the types for "creating / retrieving" are the same.

Comment: An `overloaded` of decent quality needs function pointer specializations so you can overload non-lambdas.  And given how short a simple overloaded is, can you include it in your post?

Comment: @Yakk It's tagged 11, not 17, in 11 overloaded is quite a few more lines because you can't do `using...`. I can provide a link to an 11 implementation if you think that would be more helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do compile-time type checking for an erased type. That goes against the whole point of type erasure in the first place.

However, you can get an equivalent level of safety by providing an invariant guarantee that the erased type will match the expected type.

Obviously, wether that's feasible or not depends on your design at a higher level.

Here's an example:

```
class concept {
public:
  virtual ~concept() {}
};

template<typename T>
struct model : public concept { 
  T value;
};

class Holder {
public:
  template<typename T>
  void addModel() {
    map.emplace(std::type_index(typeid(T)), std::make_unique<model<T><());
  }

  template<typename T>
  T getValue() {
    auto found = types.find(std::type_index(typeid(T)));
    if(found == types.end()) {
      throw std::runtime_error("type not found");
    }

    // no need to dynamic cast here. The invariant is covering us.
    return static_cast<model<T>*>(found->second.get())->value;
  }

private:
  // invariant: map[type] is always a model<type>
  std::map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<concept>> types;
};
```

The strong encapsulation here provides a level of safety almost equivalent to a compile-time check, since map insertions are aggressively protected to maintain the invariant.

Again, this might not work with your design, but it's a way of handling that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your runtime check occurs at the point where you exit type erasure.

If you want to compile time check the operation, move it within the type erased boundaries, or export enough information to type erase later.

So enumerate the types, like std variant.  Or enumerate the algorithms, like you did copy.  You can even mix it, like a variant of various type erased sub-algorithms for the various kinds of type stored.

This does not support any algorithm on any type polymorphism; one of the two must be enumerated for things to resolve at compile time and not have a runtime check.

Comment: But I'd have to enumerate both the algorithm and the type, or not? For example I could make a virtual get member (=enumerating the algorithm) where each overload has a different type (=enumerating the types) as an output parameter? I think this would work, but I could not leave either of them out, or could I?

Comment: @MariusHerzog No, if you enumerate the types, you get a variant.  If you enumerate the algorithm, you get something like your `copy` function of `std::function<?>::operator()`.  `get` is an *exit* from type erasure to a concrete type; naturally that involves exiting type erasure.  However, you `get` to *do something with the value*.  If you are doing 7 different things with your type-erased data, you can put those things to do with the `get` *within* the type erasure instead of outside of it where you have to do run time checks.